# Is there a way to display flat face colors in plotly for 3D Surface Charts?

Tags: 3d, plotly, surface, plotly.js

I was using matlab in creating 3D surface charts but lately moved to plolty js. Everything works fine in plotly's 3D Surface charts except that the color scheme is gradient in plotly. I am trying to get flat face colors but couldn't find a proper solution. Any idea on how to achieve this functionality in plotly ? Something similar to the image in the below link, where the colors are not distributed in a gradient manner, but distinct for each face. This is achieved using "face color : flat" option in matlab. I am looking for this functionality in plotly:-

https://www.javatpoint.com/matlab-3d-sphere

Comment: Do you just want a constant color for the entire surface?

Comment: No. I am looking for distinct colors for each face. Something like the plot in the below reference where colors are not distributed in a gradient manner :- https://www.javatpoint.com/matlab-3d-sphere

Answer (score 2):

- you can split a surface into "faces".  In this example I've split a Bloch sphere into multiple segments
- for each "face" generate a trace
- each trace can have a **colorscale** that will only assign one color

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors

#just a sphere
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
phi = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)

data = []
STEP = 20
for s, e, c in zip(range(0,len(phi),STEP), range(STEP, len(phi)+STEP, STEP), plotly.colors.sequential.Plasma):
    theta2 = theta[s:e]
    for s2, e2 in zip(range(0,len(phi),STEP), range(STEP, len(phi)+STEP, STEP)):
        
        phi2 = phi[s2:e2]
        x = np.outer(np.cos(theta2),np.sin(phi2))
        y = np.outer(np.sin(theta2),np.sin(phi2))
        z = np.outer(np.ones(STEP),np.cos(phi2))
        c = np.random.choice(plotly.colors.sequential.Plasma, 1)[0]

        data.append(
            go.Surface(
                x=x,
                y=y,
                z=z,
                colorscale=[[0,c],[1,c]],
                showscale=False
            ))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout={"width":500, "height":500, "margin":{"t":0,"b":0}})

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rob, this looks promising. For my case, I am looking to color the faces with a fixed color scale and colouring to be based on a different data (other than z). In short, I am trying to change the gradient effect to something like a flattened color pattern. Do you think that can be achieved ? Please guide

Comment: I think your input lies close to my answer. I am new to plotly , do you think colors from a fixed color scale and based on different input (other than z) can be used here ? Your help is much appreciated !!